# Is there a finite-dimensional vector space whose dimension cannot be found?

Tags: constructive-mathematics, mathematical-philosophy, foundations, lo.logic

Is there a finite-dimensional vector space whose dimension cannot be found? Assume, we have somehow constructed a vector space whose dimension is finite, but yet unknown. Is there always an algorithm to find it?

Take the example by Noam Elkies from the comments: let $V$ be the vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ spanned by $\lbrace 1,e,\pi \rbrace$. Should we believe that $\dim(V)$ is either $2$ or $3$, even if we don't know which?

Comment: This is not a real question, voting to close.

Comment: Consider the vector space whose dimension is $1$ if a particular Turing machine halts on a particular input and $0$ otherwise. 

Comment: Wow, Qiaochu...I was thinking exactly this before I opened the question. 

Comment: Qiaochu: This is not finite constructively. Thing is, the constructive definition of "finite" requires exact knowledge of the number, so this is a non-question.

Comment: I am impressed someone upvoted this...

Comment: Surely this is a real question, even though it's way too low level ...

Comment: Let $V$ be the span of $\lbrace 1, e, \pi \rbrace$ as a vector space over ${\bf Q}$.  Then $\dim(V)$ is finite, and surely equal to $3$, but nobody knows how to prove it.

Comment: From a constructivist point of view, this is a very 'real' question.  Noam Elkies' answer is quite a good one.  One can expand on that pattern to give quite substantial answers to this question.  Vote to reopen.  

Comment: I think it would be good if before the question is considered for reopening somebody makes precise in the question what 'constructed' and alike should mean in this question. At the moment the usage seems to be vague/informal (which is my issue with the question) 

Comment: @darji: There are several constructively inequivalent notions of "finite".  One requires exact knowledge of the number as you said.  Another only requires a surjection (not bijection) from a set of known finite size.  The two definitions would disagree about whether Noam Elkies's example is known to be finite-dimensional.  

Comment: Ah, okay, Andreas. But then the question is missing the most important part: the definition of the notions involved.

Comment: While Noam's example is very nice, the OP's question can be interpreted as asking for an example where the dimension cannot be found in principle. As for @Jacques Carrette's proposal to reopen, the question is so vague that of course you can construct interesting questions that the OP MIGHT have asked. It is up to the OP to ask a reasonable question.

Comment: @Igor: It was me who upvoted this question, any question that has Noam Elkies spending some time and these many comments deserves to be treated at least in my mind. Granted that it requires editing, but I wouldn't just close this question. Anyway, perhaps this should be in meta. 

Comment: @Reimundo Heluani: you make it sound as if editing and closing where mutually exclusive. In some sense, the opposite is the case. A main point of closing a vague question is to give time for editing, while (temporarily) holding back answers that then, after a clarifiying edit, might seemm off-topic or besides the point. 
For a more authorative account (not for this specific question but in general) please see François's contribution, in particular 3. in his numbered list, in the following recent meta thread http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1156/our-standards-and-how-we-enforce-them/

Comment: on META: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1158/is-it-ok-to-upvote-a-question-just-for-not-being-complete-nonsense/ 

Comment: @Yrogirg: Let me add my voice to the chorus that this question is close to a good one, but should be revised.  There is some discussion of the mathematics at the meta thread Will Jagy links to.  When you have made appropriate revisions, please flag the post for "moderator attention" and ask that it be reopened --- my impression from the meta discussion is that there are a number of experts who are itching to discuss some of the related mathematics.